# Left or right aligning text in the center of a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I'd like to have a table that has the text in the middle of a cell. But the text inside the cell and the heading all need to be left or right aligned to the other text in the other cells.

The reason I need the text in the center of the cell is because some of the table cells get highlighted and it looks a bit silly having the text sitting on the edge.

Have a look at the image below to see what I mean:

[image]

Here's a JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/php58knw/1/

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>$1</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
```

```
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > td {
  border-top: 0;
}
.table > tbody + tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.table .table {
  background-color: white;
}

.table-condensed > thead > tr > th,
.table-condensed > thead > tr > td,
.table-condensed > tbody > tr > th,
.table-condensed > tbody > tr > td,
.table-condensed > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-condensed > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: green;
}

.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > th {
  background-color: orange;
}

table col[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  display: table-column;
}

table td[class*="col-"],
table th[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```
.table-number {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #545454;
}

.table-heading {
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}

table.table {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #3c3c3c;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table.table thead tr th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
}
table.table tbody tr td {
  border: none;
  color: #989898;
  border-top: none;
  line-height: 2;
}
table.table tbody tr td:first-child {
  color: #000;
  text-align: right;
}
table.table tbody tr td.num, table.table tbody tr td.perc, table.table tbody tr td.curr {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}
table.table tbody tr td.num.highlight, table.table tbody tr td.perc.highlight, table.table tbody tr td.curr.highlight {
  background-color: #ff8080;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #FFF;
}
table.table tbody tr td.num.highlight-alt, table.table tbody tr td.perc.highlight-alt, table.table tbody tr td.curr.highlight-alt {
  background-color: #8080ff;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #FFF;
}

</style>


<div class="table-container">
                <div class="table-number">Table 1:</div>
                <div class="table-heading">Developed world tobacco industry: 1973-2010</div>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Volume p.a.</th>
                            <th>Real price p.a.</th>
                            <th>Real revenue p.a.</th>
                            <th>Real GDP p.a.</th>
                            <th>Period</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>United States</td>
                            <td class="perc">-1.5%</td>
                            <td class="perc">3.4%</td>
                            <td class="perc">1.9%</td>
                            <td class="perc">2.8%</td>
                            <td class="num">1,973</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Australia</td>
                            <td class="perc">-1.9%</td>
                            <td class="curr highlight">$9,999.00</td>
                            <td class="curr">R5,000.00</td>
                            <td class="curr">R5,000.00</td>
                            <td class="num">1,973</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>UK</td>
                            <td class="perc">-1.0%</td>
                            <td class="perc">3.0%</td>
                            <td class="perc">1.3%</td>
                            <td class="perc highlight-alt">2.0%</td>
                            <td class="num">1,988</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Average</td>
                            <td class="perc highlight">-1.4%</td>
                            <td class="perc highlight">3.6%</td>
                            <td class="perc">1.8%</td>
                            <td class="perc">2.7%</td>
                            <td class="num">0</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try CSS? `.YourTable td { text-align:left; }`

Comment: I've updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
table.table tbody tr td.perc, table.table tbody tr th,
table.table tbody tr td.num, table.table tbody tr td.curr {
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 5%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n20h0vdL/

Comment: Thanks, this works pretty well, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer :( Otherwise I totally would.